# UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and transform

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, transform, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using the below to modify UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes. Method 1 works but not Method 2, anyone can help explain the difference?

```
guard let newAttrs = attributes?.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, 
      let imageViewInfo = imageViewInfo else { return nil }

let center = imageViewInfo.center

//Method 1
newAttrs.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
let x = (newAttrs.center.x-center.x) * scale + igCenter.x
let y = (newAttrs.center.y-center.y) * scale + igCenter.y
newAttrs.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

//Method 2
newAttrs.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -center.x, y: -center.y)
  .scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
  .translatedBy(x: igCenter.x, y: igCenter.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform

to change position of the view/cell, modify 'center' instead.